# Why do we have momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, mass, velocity

Momentum is the defined as the product of mass and velocity and can be thought as measuring how much motion something has. However, it is not clear to me why we need momentum and why force is not sufficient to explain nearly all the phenomena. Consider a larger mass moving at the same speed as an object of smaller mass. We say the object of larger mass is harder to stop, as it has more momentum.

However, could we not just say the object of larger mass exerts more force, so it requires a greater force to stop it? The use of momentum is not entirely clear to me.

Comment: Even if it’s all forces under the hood momentum macroscopically has a lot of meaning in simplifying calculations and is experimentally measured (many animals know it at least vaguely). When calculating the collision of cars and pool balls do we really want to think of them as vibrating bunches molecules exerting electrostatic and Pauli exclusion forces when they collide? No, OFTEN (but not always) we would rather forget those details and think of them as objects with mass and velocity whose momentum let’s us predict their dynamics

Comment: I guess to be true to the spirit of your question: even if at this time we believe it’s only forces under the hood, momentum exists as an experimentally justified idea and calculational tool, whose utility ranges from the galactic to even the quantum regime.

Comment: In quantum mechanics, there's essentially no such thing as force, but there *is* a well-defined notion of momentum.

Comment: Exerts more force on what? Forces are interactions *between* systems. You can't say object A exerts a force without specifying the object B on which it exerts that force. By contrast, objects do have momentum. Object A and object B both have their own momentum.

Comment: Why do we have the number 7 when we could just write 1+1+1+1+1+1+1 all the time?

Comment: "so it requires a greater force to stop it" - Note that a larger mass object *can* be stopped with the same force as a smaller mass object. It will just take longer.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Question seems perfectly clear to me, and Dale's excellent answer below shows that it was clear to them too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Momentum is the primary quantity because it is conserved. Force is only useful because for mechanical systems it is the rate of change of momentum. But momentum is more general, things like electromagnetic fields have momentum even if they have no mass and no acceleration and therefore no force in the usual sense.

Momentum also has important meaning through Noether’s theorem. The fact that the laws of physics are the same here, in Paris, on Mars, and in Andromeda implies that there must be a conserved momentum. The actual details of those laws doesn’t matter. Any laws with that symmetry would necessarily result in some conserved momentum.

So you could get rid of forces, $\vec F$, simply replacing them with rates of change of momentum $\dot {\vec p}$. But not the reverse since it is $\vec p$ that is conserved, that follows from the spatial symmetry of the laws of physics, and that applies to non-mechanical systems.

Comment: In other words: Momentum is the conserved quantity, and forces are the exchange of momentum.

Answer (score 7):

One or two observations...

(a) It's reasonable to use momentum as a measure of motion (meaning impulse needed to bring to a halt) because a body of mass $2m$ moving with velocity $\vec v$ is found to need the same impulse to stop it as the total impulse needed to stop two bodies of mass $m$ moving side-by-side with the same velocity, $\vec v$.

(b) Momentum is a conserved quantity: the vector sum of the momenta of bodies in a system doesn't change, provided no forces from outside the system act on the bodies. This principle has many applications, and conserved quantities are prized by physicists.

(c) At high speeds momentum is still conserved, but only if we define the momentum, $\vec p$, of a body of mass $m$ moving with velocity $\vec v$ as
$$\vec p=m\gamma\ \vec v\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{in which}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \gamma=\frac 1{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}.$$
So momentum is not a mere synonym for $mv$.

Comment: that is a body with _rest mass_ m in the above equation

Comment: @Cecil Ward  I believe that, for the last forty years or so, there has been general agreement among teachers of Special Relativity that *relativistic mass* is an unnecessary, and possibly confusing, concept that shouldn't be taught. The term *mass* is reserved for a property that a body has irrespective of its motion. There is no need to call it 'rest mass', if one no longer speaks of 'relativistic mass'.

Answer (score 4):

Momentum is a useful concept because it describes the current state of a
system, whereas unopposed forces act to change that state.  That is,
force is a *cause*, and change in momentum is its *effect*.

Mathematically, momentum ($p$) is mass ($m$) times velocity ($v$):

\begin{equation}
p = m v
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Meanwhile, force ($F$) is mass times acceleration ($a$):

\begin{equation}
F = m a
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

But acceleration is change of velocity per unit time:

\begin{equation}
a = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} v
\tag{3}
\end{equation}

Substituting that into (2):

\begin{equation}
F = m \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} v
\tag{4}
\end{equation}

and then assuming mass does not change:

\begin{equation}
F = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} m v
\tag{5}
\end{equation}

Therefore, substituting (1):

\begin{equation}
F = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} p
\tag{6}
\end{equation}

That is, force is the change of momentum per unit time.

You contemplate distinguishing a moving heavy mass from a moving lighter
mass by observing the heavy mass requires more force to stop.  That is
only true if the *time* to stop them is held fixed; otherwise, for
example, both masses will eventually stop even if the braking force is
the same, just after different amounts of time.

If we do insist that the braking time is the same, for example one
second to bring the mass to a stop, then indeed "braking force to stop
in one second" is effectively the same thing as momentum, since the
$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}$ in (6) has been fixed at
$\frac{1}{s}$.

But "braking force to stop in one second" is an awkward phrase, and the
choice of "one second" somewhat arbitrary.  So we instead use the term
"momentum" to capture the same basic idea without attachment to any
particular time period.

(As noted in other answers, momentum is also a *conserved* quantity,
which makes it arguably more *important* than force, but I think that's
getting ahead of the basic question of why it exists as a concept at
all.)

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out, conservation of momentum, when applicable, is a useful tool. Consider the typical example of the elastic collision of two balls on a frictionless surface. Using the principle of conservation of momentum, we can solve for the final velocities of the objects without having to know the details of what happens the instant the objects meet.

Answer (score 0):

Why do we have momentum? In one word: *convenience.*

[Newton didn't mention momentum when he formulated his laws](https://www.physics.utoronto.ca/%7Ejharlow/teaching/everyday06/reading01.htm), so technically you can solve any problem without it, assuming you can solve it using momentum.

1. An object at rest will remain at rest unless acted upon by an external and unbalanced force . An object in motion will remain in motion unless acted upon by an external and unbalanced force
2. The alteration of motion is ever proportional to the motive force impressed; and is made in the direction of the right line in which that force is impressed. If a force generates a motion, a double force will generate double the motion, a triple force triple the motion, whether that force be impressed altogether and at once, or gradually and successively. And this motion (being always directed the same way with the generating force), if the body moved before, is added to or subtracted from the former motion, according as they directly conspire with or are directly contrary to each other; or obliquely joined, when they are oblique, so as to produce a new motion compounded from the determination of both.
3. All forces occur in pairs, and these two forces are equal in magnitude and opposite in direction.

OTOH there are many useful things that enable an average undergraduate today to solve problems that would have stretched Newton's intellect to its limits; momentum is one of them.